# Why is the arcgis.geometry.buffer method failing on supposed empty geometries?

Tags: python, feature-service, arcgis-python-api

I am attempting to buffer some output after querying a feature service using the `arcgis` API for Python:

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayerCollection
from arcgis.geometry import Geometry, buffer

# obtain the LOMR feature
nfhl_url = "https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer"
nfhl = FeatureLayerCollection(nfhl_url)
lomr = nfhl.layers[1]

# define the desired spatial ref for the project
sr = 2876 # NAD83(HARN) / Colorado North (ftUS)

# start an anonymous GIS session
anon_gis = GIS()

# query the service
boulder_lomrs = lomr.query(where="DFIRM_ID = '08013C'", out_sr=sr)

# create a list of geometries to buffer
lomr_geoms = [l.geometry for l in boulder_lomrs.features]

# buffer the polygons
lomr_buffer = buffer(geometries=lomr_geoms, 
                     in_sr=sr, 
                     distances=[1], 
                     unit='ftUS', 
                     out_sr=sr, 
                     buffer_sr=sr, 
                     union_results=True, 
                     gis=anon_gis)
```

The error I receive is:

```py
Exception: Unable to complete operation.
The operation was attempted on an empty geometry.
(Error Code: 400)
```

However, I've checked that all geometries in `lomr_geoms` are valid and not-empty. This leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong with the spatial references and/or units.

Why am I getting this error? The [ESRI documentation on the buffer method](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html#buffer) is not very specific on syntax, and they wrongly claim that `unit` will be derived from the `in_sr` parameter (I tried running the buffer without the `unit` parameter and it failed because it's required).

**EDIT 1**

I've tried redefining how the list of geometries is constructed:

```py
# create a list of geometries to buffer
lomr_geoms = [Geometry(l.geometry) for l in boulder_lomrs.features]

# buffer the polygons
lomr_buffer = buffer(geometries=lomr_geoms, 
                     in_sr=sr, 
                     distances=[1], 
                     unit='ftUS', 
                     out_sr=sr, 
                     buffer_sr=sr, 
                     union_results=True, 
                     gis=anon_gis)
```

I still get the same error code, but for a different reason:

```
Exception: Unable to complete operation.
(Error Code: 400)
```

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts here, I have been having similar issues with my buffering efforts. Wondering if you could expands on your code further?
I manage to get GeomotryJob to execute/run...but now I can't access the results.

Comment: Hate how the efforts were necessary, ha! This code was written using `arcgis==1.8.3`, so I'm not sure the GeometryJob thing was implemented quite yet. If your struggles remain fruitless, my suggestion would be to convert your query output to a geopandas dataframe and use shapely to do any geometry processing. So much more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the units. According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/issues/523), it's because the user has to input the unit as one of the constants that go into ArcObjects.

See [this reference table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#/esriSRUnitType_Constants/000w00000042000000/) to get the correct unit for your needs.

Altogether, the change just needed to be:

```py
lomr_buffer = buffer(geometries=lomr_geoms, 
                     in_sr=sr, 
                     distances=[1], 
                     unit=9003, #US Survey ft 
                     out_sr=sr, 
                     buffer_sr=sr, 
                     union_results=True, 
                     gis=anon_gis)
```